# Maatwebsite Excel with Laravel 9 and PHP 8

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, composer-php

I installed Maatwebsite with Laravel 9 and PHP 8 using this command **composer require maatwebsite/excel:*** . Then I got this notice at the end of the installation:[image]

I then register it in the config/app.php and I run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

I got this: [image]

Here is my config/app.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Zuuro ::| - We provide you
    best and easy
    services that
    make life easier'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services the application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Faker Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This locale will be used by the Faker PHP library when generating fake
    | data for your database seeds. For example, this will be used to get
    | localized telephone numbers, street address information and more.
    |
    */

    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Maintenance Mode Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These configuration options determine the driver used to determine and
    | manage Laravel's "maintenance mode" status. The "cache" driver will
    | allow maintenance mode to be controlled across multiple machines.
    |
    | Supported drivers: "file", "cache"
    |
    */

    'maintenance' => [
        'driver' => 'file',
        // 'store'  => 'redis',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider:: class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'ExampleClass' => App\Example\ExampleClass::class,
        'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
    ])->toArray(),

];
```

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "*",
        "orchestra/testbench": "^7.11",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "dev-NumberFormatMask-Helpers",
        "predis/predis": "^2.0",
        "psr/simple-cache": "1.0",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.38"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I tried to install Maatwebsite/Excel but wasn't working out for me, I was receiving error which I don't get the source.

Comment: "I tried to install Maatwebsite/Excel but wasn't working out for me" - what does that mean? As far as I see, there are only notices thrown at the end of the installation. Which version did you install in the end? `*` matches a lot of versions

Comment: Pretty strange: I've checked some versions of `ExcelServiceProvider` on Github, but none contains 156 lines. Also, please share how the given problem is related to HTML or SQL

Answer (score -1):

Go to the php.ini file and remove ;

before

`;extension=gd`

after

`extension=gd`

execute the command to change your cache

`composer require psr/simple-cache ^2.0`

Then install maatwebsiteexcel

`composer require maatwebsite/excel`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Which parts of the question makes you think that gd is related?

Comment: maatwebsiteexcel needs gd extension in order to be succesfully installed in your project, I have faced this problem before in my previous projects Laravel 9 with php 8

Comment: And what makes you think that the initial problem is related to that? If the gd extension was missing, requiring that package would have thrown an error message telling you that gd is missing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).